# Ruby on Rails #find_each and #each. is this bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that `find_each` has been designed to consume smaller memory than `each`.
I found some code that other people wrote long ago. and I think that it's wrong.

Think about this codes.

```
 users = User.where(:active => false) # What this line does actually? Nothing?
 users.find_each do |user|
  # update or do something..
  user.update(:do_something => "yes")
 end
```

in this case, It will store all user objects to the `users` variable. so we already populated the full amount of memory space. There is no point using find_each later on.

*Am I correct?*

so in other words, If you want to use `find_each`, ***you always need to use it with ActiveRecord::Relation object***. Like this.

```
User.where(:active => false).find_each do |user|
  # do something...
end
```

What do you think guys?

---

***Update***

in `users = User.where(:active => false)` line,

Some developer insists that rails never execute query unless we don't do anything with that variable.
What if we have a class with initialize method that has query?

```
class Test

  def initialize
    @users = User.where(:active => true)
  end

  def do_something
    @user.find_each do |user|
      # do something really..
    end
  end

end
```

If we call `Test.new`, what would happen? Nothing will happen?

Comment: One of the advantages of rails is that the queries are run when you use the data, so, in your example, only when you run the `find_each` the query is executed, so it should not be an issue setting the query into a variable and then processing it

Comment: what do you mean? so say we have only one line of code. `users = User.where(:active => false)` then it means that it never executed query?.... @Aguardientico

Comment: Your proposed improvement does exactly the same thing as the first snippet.

Comment: @JinLim right, if you only have the first line, it will not be executed. BTW if you test it in a rails console, it is executed because the REPL inspects the sentence

Comment: @Aguardientico would you please see my Updates? on questions.

Comment: "If we call Test.new, what would happen?" - this is trivial to check, isn't it? Just put in a query large enough for you to notice the pause, if it were to be executed.

Comment: "What if we have a class with initialize method that has query?" - you still don't do anything with the results of the query (if you only call `Test.new`)

Comment: You might find [The Rails Style Guide](https://rails.rubystyle.guide/) very useful, and [rubocop-rails](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-rails/2.8/index.html) which enforces it.

Comment: @JinLim as Sergio said, it is pretty simple to test, you can open your `development.log`, in a console you can do `foo = Test.new` and verify if the query is executed or not, then you can do `foo.do_something` and verify if the query is executed

Comment: Or `Rails.logger.level=0` shows you the execution of any queries through the console.

Answer (score 3):

`users = User.where(:active => false)` doesn't run a query against the database and it doesn't return an array with all inactive users. Instead, `where` returns an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html). Such a relation basically describes a database query that hasn't run yet. The defined query is only run against the database when the actual records are needed. This happens for example when you run one of the following methods on that relation: `find`, `to_a`, `count`, `each`, and many others.

That means the change you did isn't a huge improvement, because it doesn't change went and how the database is queried.

But IMHO that your code is still slightly better because when you do not plan to reuse the relation then why assign it to a variable in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the explain. what about this? `result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT id, title, body FROM posts')`  this will run query? I also don't think I can use `find_each` on `result` though. Rails is interesting..

Comment: `exec_query` run the query immediately and you are right you cannot use `exec_query` together with `find_each`. Because `find_each` works by loading chunks of data and it needs to be able to add `limit` and `offset` to the query which obviously only works if the query hasn't run before. `ActiveRecord::Relations` can be extended (for example by chaining more conditions with `where`) before you run them and that is exactly what `find_each` does.

Comment: Just one detail - `find_each` doesn't use offset for iteration over the records, because it is very slow for processing of big amount of rows. It iterates over tables primary key in `asc`/`desc` order instead (order can be set by the params). This is probably the second biggest difference between `each` and `find_each`, `find_each` ignores explicit ordering if it is set in the query in favour of better performance by iterating over ids.

Comment: @edariedl is right all the `ActiveRecord::Batches` methods use `in_batches` which collects all the ids greater than (or less than) the last id of the preceding execution with a limit. So essentially `Model.where(Model.arel_table[Model.primary_key].gt(n)).order(Model.primary_key => :asc).limit(x)` where `n` is the last primary key e.g. `x =1000` then `n = 0`,`n=1000`,`n=2000`,etc. (assuming no deletions)

Answer (score 3):

```
users = User.where(:active => false)
users.find_each do |user|
```

```
User.where(:active => false).find_each do |user|
```

Those do the same thing.

The only difference is the first one stores the ActiveRecord::Relation object in `users` before calling `#find_each` on it.

This isn't a Rails thing, it applies to all of Ruby. It's [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) common to most object-oriented languages.

```
array = Call.some_method
array.each{ |item| do_something(item) }
```

```
Call.some_method.each{ |item| do_something(item) }
```

Again, same thing. The only difference is in the first the intermediate `array` will persist, whereas in the second the array will be built and then eventually deallocated.

---

> If we call Test.new, what would happen? Nothing will happen?

Exactly. Rails will make an ActiveRecord::Relation and it will defer actually contacting the database until you actually do a query.

This lets you chain queries together.

```
@inactive_users = User.where(active: false).order(name: :asc)
```

Later you can to the query

```
# Inactive users whose favorite color is green ordered by name.
@inactive_users.where(favorite_color: :green).find_each do |user|
   ...
end
```

No query is made until `find_each` is called.

In general, pass around relations rather than arrays of records. Relations are more flexible and if it's never used there's no cost.

---

`find_each` is special in that it works in batches to avoid consuming too much memory on large tables.

A common mistake is to write this:

```
User.where(:active => false).each do |user|
```

Or worse:

```
User.all.each do |user|
```

Calling `each` on an ActiveRecord::Relation will pull all the results into memory before iterating. This is bad for large tables.

`find_each` will load the results in batches of 1000 to avoid using too much memory. It hides this batching from you.

There are other methods which work in batches, see [ActiveRecord::Batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html).

---

For more see the [Rails Style Guide](https://rails.rubystyle.guide/) and use [rubocop-rails](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-rails/2.8/index.html) to scan your code for issues and make suggestions and corrections.